# Why does I keep on getting "Cars() takes no argument"?

Tags: python

I think Car() should take 4 arguments. Does not my constructor specify the arguments that a car object should take?

```py
class Car: 
    def _init_(self, rego, model, color, price):
        self.rego = rego
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.price = price


    def car_rego(self):
        return self.rego

    def car_model(self):
        return self.model

    def car_color(self):
        return self.color

    def car_price(self):
        return self.price

my_car = Car("A123", "BMW", "Red", 1000)
print(my_car.car_price())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's supposed to be `__init__` not `_init_`.

By the way, it's not idiomatic in Python to write these methods that just return an attribute. There's no need for them at all. Just let users use the attribute directly.